# Recursion with lists vs Recursion with strings in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion

When I use the following code to print all subsets of the string "abc", the code works as expected, printing :
ab
a
b

```
#complete search

arr = "ab"

def all_subsets(a, i, curr):
    if i == len(a):
        print(curr)
        return
    else:
        all_subsets(a, i+1, curr + (a[i]))
        all_subsets(a, i+1, curr)
    

all_subsets(arr, 0, "")
```

But when I use this code, which should do the same thing as the above code, I get an error:

```
#complete search

arr = [1,2,3]

def all_subsets(a, i, curr):
    if i == len(a):
        print(curr)
        return
    all_subsets(a, i+1, curr.append(a[i]))
    all_subsets(a, i+1, curr)
    

all_subsets(arr, 0, [])
```

The error is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'". I am not sure why this is arising as the code should be doing the same as the first code, but using lists instead of strings? Could anyone point me toward why this is the case?

Comment: On the first recursion, you append `1` to `curr`, and then pass `None` to the next call.  `append` is an in-place operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array.append()` is a function that returns a `None` value. So in the first recursive call, you pass a `None` value instead of the appended array as you'd want. Here's a solution:

```py
#complete search

arr = [1,2,3]

def all_subsets(a, i, curr):
    if i == len(a):
        print(curr)
        return

    all_subsets(a, i+1, curr + [a[i]])
    all_subsets(a, i+1, curr)
    

all_subsets(arr, 0, [])
```

As an illustrative example, `[1, 2, 3] + [4]` gives you `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, which really helps in reducing complexity and improving readibility of your code than any append method could.